# Result of multiple table query is array of non-array

Tags: javascript, arrays, breeze

The resulting data of a multiple table query (see http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/query-examples#Lookups) is not exactly what I expected.  I expected an array (item for each table) of arrays (of entity fields).  But, what I get is an array of sort-of arrays.  The outer array is -- as expected -- filled with an item for each table. But, the inner objects are not typed as Array.  They do actually have members named like indexed items (0, 1, 2, ...), but since it's not an array, I cannot use length or forEach.  Is this a bug in Breeze?

Note that when I query for items from one table, the result is typed as array (of entity fields).

Here's my server code:

```
[HttpGet]
public object _Combo()
{
   return new IOrderedQueryable[] { _contextProvider.Context.Company, _contextProvider.Context.Project, _contextProvider.Context.ProjectArea };
}
```

Here's my client code:

```
entityManager.executeQuery(breeze.EntityQuery.from("_Combo"))
    .then(function (data) {
        var companies = data.results[0];
        //companies is not an array, but does have numbered members!
    }).fail(queryFailed);
```

Comment: You are correct about the shape of the thing returned by the server code as you wrote it; it's not an array but rather a hash with properties named "0", "1", "2", etc. I was surprised by that myself.  You'll find an example of your approach in DocCode (see `NorthwindController.LookupsArray`). Is it a bug or a feature :)? While this is survivable (you can iterate over the properties of a hash), the approach I prefer (also in DocCode as `Lookups`) is the one described by Jay in his answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what "shape" you want returned from looking at your "_Combo" code? But  if it is an anon type that contains Companies, Projects and ProjectAreas, then the following should work. You don't need to return a IQueryable unless you plan to have a client side filter applied on the server.

```
[HttpGet]
public object _Combo()
{
    return new { Companies = ContextProvider.Context.Company.ToList(), 
                 Projects = ContextProvider.Context.Project.ToList(),  
                 ProjectAreas = ContextProvider.Context.ProjectAreas.ToList() } 

}
```

This will return a single element array with its one item containing an object with three properties: "Companies", "Projects" and "ProjectAreas".  Each of which is an array of the corresponding entities.  All of these entities will have been added to the entityManager. Hope this helps.